# Run different patterns on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to generate a random pattern every time I hover over div(svg).

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ksv1205/pen/zZXRaq)

This is my code so far:

```
var items = ["#pattern-rect", "#pattern-circle", "#pattern-triangle","#pattern-star"];
$("div").hover(function(){
  $("g").css({"visibility": "visible"});
  var item = Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length);
  $("g").css({"fill": "url(items[item])"});
  }, function(){
  $("g").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
  });
$("g").css({"visibility": "hidden"});



  $("g").css({"fill": "url(items[item])"}); This line is not working.
```

Comment: then what would be the solution to run different patterns on hover. @RobertLongson

Comment: $("g").css({"fill": "url(items[item])"}); @RobertLongson

Comment: the url is not accepting any variable. Can you explain in brief? @RobertLongson

Comment: items is an array which contains all the pattern id's. and item is a variable which generates the random index from the array items. and then I assign the pattern id to the g element $("g").css({"fill": "url(items[item])"}); and its not working. Here is the codepen link - http://codepen.io/ksv1205/pen/zZXRaq   @RobertLongson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("g").css({"fill": "url(items[item])"});
```

would need to be something like:

```
$("g").css({"fill": "url(" + items[item] + ")"});
```

Comment: Thanks. That's working. I need to generate unique patterns on hovering div. But when I do this with random javascript function it generates identical patterns more than 1 time in a row. How to solve this.

Comment: @KaranSingh and now do you understand the difference between a string literal and a variable?

Comment: @KaranSingh Many possible approaches. For example: (1) check that the new random number is not the same as the last one, or (2) randomly shuffle your pattern array at the start (then take them in order) instead of selecting one at random